i want to get all the import string from vue/ts/tsx file, how to do this?
i want to get all the from "$string".


<template>
  <SignaturePage/>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
import { useI18n } from '@/i18n'

const { t } = useI18n()
const { goPrev, goNext } = useOLSteps()
const { errorHandler } = useOLErrorHandler()
</script>



and i use this rule


{
  rule: {
    // regex: "/[^.]+[^/]$",
    // regex: ".+$",
    kind: "string_fragment",
    any: [
      {
        inside: {
          stopBy: "end",
          kind: "import_statement",
        },
      },
      {
        inside: {
          stopBy: "end",
          kind: "call_expression",
          has: { field: "function", regex: "^import$" },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
}





export { SgNode, Lang, parse } from "@ast-grep/napi"
const ast = parse(Lang.TypeScript, contentFromPath)



I tried it briefly, and I don't know why the first one is 'pinia', but 'vue' is skipped.
And this involves language injections. How should this rule be designed and how should it be understood?

languageInecjtion is not supported by napi. You can instead extract the script and apply the rule with the extracted string.
